# How to use "{0, ordinal}" in ChoiceFormat without Android ICU

Tags: java, messageformat

I'm trying to obtain english ordinals to use in a leaderboard through choice format.

My current solution is to have something like this :

```
{0,choice,0#th|1#st|2#nd|3#rd|3<th}
```

And use this is a parameter.

```
int pos = position % 100 >= 11 && position % 100 <= 13 ? 0 : position % 10
```

This works well but I found out you can use `{0,ordinal}` with ICU.

Is there any easy way to make it work without ICU?

Comment: Can you post the solution that worked for you

Comment: I used what I included in the question. I passed a parameter

Comment: did you pass this to message format?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
import android.icu.text.MessageFormat

fun toOrdinal(day: String): String {
    val formatter = MessageFormat("{0,ordinal}", Locale.getDefault())
    return formatter.format(arrayOf(day.toInt()))
}
```

You will get these results:

```
1 -> 1st
2 -> 2nd
3 -> 3rd
4 -> 4th
6 -> (...)
```